# Angular / nodejs : How to ng-repeat all products from database for an online shop? controller etc doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using node for the backend and angular for the frontend and am trying to display the products, however, nothing is being displayed. For the database, I am using Postgres (Sequelize) (everything works here and I dont have any problems with my models etc. I have been looking at other code, searched this forum etc but dont know what is wrong with my code-could be either the backend route is wrong or the angular code but I cant tell what it is. Also, I am using Gulp(so no script tags are necessary).

Could anyone help? Thanks!
Ps. if I missed to include anything, pls let me know. I didnt include my database code as Im sure (so far) the problem is not there.

the backend (with node):

server/app:

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes'));
```

server/app/index.js:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
module.exports = router;

router.use('/products', require('./products'))
router.use(function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).end();
});
```

server/app/routes/products:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Products=require('../../db/models/products');

router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    Products.findAll() 
    .then(function(all){
        res.send(all)
    })
    .catch(next);
})

module.exports = router;
```

frontend with angular:

browser/js/shop/shop.controller.js:

```
app.controller('ShopCtrl', function ($scope, ProductsFactory) {
     ProductsFactory.fetchAll()
        .then(function(products){
            $scope.products=products;
        })
      $scope.allProducts={};
```

browser/js/shop/shop.js:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('shop', {
        url: '/shop',
        controller: 'ShopController',
        templateUrl: 'js/shop/shop.html',

    });

});
```

browser/js/shop/shop.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browser/js/shop/shop.js: you use "ShopController" as the controller for the route but you named it "ShopCtrl" in shop.controller.js

Rename either so they match

Comment: oh wow totally missed that! Thank you! its crazy how long I spend on this one not realizing i just misspelled a word :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)